# Determine the order of the zero of the function $f(z)=z(1-\cos^2z)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need to determine the order of the zero of the function

$$
f(z)=z(1-\cos^2z)
$$

The zero is $z=0$ and now I want to determine the order. This is my work so far:

$$
f(z)=z(1-\cos^2z)=z(\sin^2z)=z\left(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\right)^2
    =-\frac{z}{4}(e^{i2z}+e^{-i2z}-2)
$$

so we can rewrite $f$ as

$$
f(z)=-\frac{z}{2}(\cos2z-1)
$$

Using the Maclaurin expansion of $\cos$,

$$
\cos2z=1-\frac{(2z)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2z)^4}{4!}- \cdots
$$

we have

$$
-1+\cos2z=-\frac{(2z)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2z)^4}{4!}- \cdots
$$

so

$$
f(z)=-\frac{z}{2}\left(  -\frac{(2z)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2z)^4}{4!}- \cdots \right)
    =z^3\left( 1-\frac{(2z)^2}{4!}+ \cdots \right)
$$

And therefore, the order of the zero must be 3. However, my textbook says it's 5.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: The "answers at the back of the book" are not always correct.

Comment: I think there's an error in your book. If you factor your function as $z(1-\cos z)(1+\cos z)$, you also find $3$.

Comment: One way to double-check that you are correct is to divide the original $f(z)$ by $(z-0)^3$ and observe that the limit as $z\rightarrow 0$ is $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right (and the textbook is wrong). For $z \to 0$ we have 
$$
 f(z) = z \sin^2 z = z \left( z + O(z^3) \right)^2 = z^3 \left( 1 + O(z^2) \right)^2
$$
so that $f$ has a zero of order three at $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly is $O$ here?

Comment: That is the [“big O notation”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Here $O(z^2)$ summarizes the terms $z^n$ with $n \ge 2$.